# Get Salesforce Account fields

Tags: api, salesforce

I am doing the specifications using Salesforce API
I searched so much but didn't find the list of fields that i could retrieve using GET method
Someone could provide me the link that give me this list please ?

I just found this link 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_get_field_values.htm

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a "describe" call. [It'll return a list of all objects your user can see in the org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_describeGlobal.htm) and it'll include links [how to get more detailed info about all fields on say Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm). (you can jump straight to describing an Account if you want, the links are constructed in a predictable pattern)

"Describes" are limited to what your Profile can see so if the profile lacks the "Read" checkbox on some object - it won't appear in the results.

Go to https://workbench.developerforce.com for example and experiment (from menu select Utilities -> REST explorer)

1. Base call that lists all APIs available to you: `/services/data/v41.0`
2. List of all sObjects & links to obtain more info about them: `/services/data/v41.0/sobjects`
3. Detailed info about Account, including fields: `/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Account/describe`

[image]

[image]