# In Salesforce How can i write Select * query in SOQL with Rest call

Tags: salesforce, soql

I want to get all objects with a Rest call using the SOQL syntax.
I know that this is not possible, but there is a  [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780413/salesforce-soql-query-to-fetch-all-the-fields-on-the-entity), but I was wondering if there is a workaround using REST.

I want to achieve something like this (So I don't want to specify the fields)

```
/services/data/v36.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Contact
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Salesforce Account fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436494/get-salesforce-account-fields)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd neet to construct the query string dynamically, exactly the same way as in the workaround you linked. You just need to call describe API first.